# Running an ansbile handler as an one time thing

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Very frequently when I'm making changes to an ansible playbook (or role) I am working with some something like this

```
tasks:
  ...
  - name: task x
    notify: handler a
  ...
  - name: task y
  ...
handlers:
  ...
  - name: handler a
  ...
```

Now during the development, **task x** succeeds and performs a *change* but **task y** fails because there's an error in it. **handler a** is not *notified*.

Later on I manage to fix **task y** and it performs its *change* but since **task x** was already changed in the previous run, it reports *no change* and **handler a** remains not *notified*.

I guess I should have run it with *--force-handlers* but now that the deal is done, what is the correct way to force **handler a** to run now.

Comment: You want it to run after `x` completes or `y` fails?

Comment: please check if the question is clearer now

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can force the handler to run by adding the following after task x:

`- meta: flush_handlers`

Of course now you are in a predicament where you are relying on a changed status for the handler to run so this isn't much good to you.

You could add `changed_when: True` to  task x to get the handler to run and then revert it. There is no correct way to get it to run because it is relying on the changed status of the notifying task

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/meta_module.html for documentation on the `meta` module.